# Unity How does Time.smoothDeltaTime work

Tags: unity, timestep

I can't seem to find any actual information on what [Time.smoothDeltaTime](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-smoothDeltaTime.html) does or how it works.

I would assume it takes a rolling average of previous deltaTimes but how does it do that? Is the average asymptotic? How sensitive is it to outliers? What is it's actual intended use case?

If anyone could explain how it works, or link to a resource on what it is doing it would be really helpful.

Comment: Do you have a specific problem in your game that you hope smoothDeltaTime might help you solve? Even if we can't find a precise definition of how it's calculated, we might still be able to help you solve that problem if you tell us about it.

Comment: [Some users in this thread worked out empirically what the formula seems to be](https://forum.unity.com/threads/time-smoothdeltatime.10253/#post-2128487) — it might be worth verifying whether that matches your experience in your current version.